# Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'floatLabel'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

```
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'floatLabel'.
```

I have used demo code from link

https://stackblitz.com/angular/moyrdxvdbdxv

https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/examples

**HTML**

```html
<div class="example-container">
    <form class="example-container" [formGroup]="options">
        <mat-checkbox formControlName="hideRequired">Hide required marker</mat-checkbox>
        <div>
            <label>Float label: </label>
            <mat-radio-group formControlName="floatLabel">
                <mat-radio-button value="auto">Auto</mat-radio-button>
                <mat-radio-button value="always">Always</mat-radio-button>
                <mat-radio-button value="never">Never</mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: StackBlitz seems to work fine after the initial error of some import: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymw1gc?file=app/form-field-label-example.html If this is a demo your code is based on, it doesn't help that you show us that code. The error is somewhere in YOUR code. so if this was not your code, please provide StackBlitz with your code showcasing the issue :)

Comment: thanks i debug again and found  MatRadioModule was missing in Import app.module.ts